# How do you fill uneven pandas dataframe column with first value in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'Name' : ['John'], 'Last Name': ['Smith'], 'Activity':['Run', 'Jump', 'Hide', 'Swim', 'Eat', 'Sleep']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

How do I make it so 'John' & 'Smith' are populated in each 'Activity' that he does in a dataframe?

Comment: How would you split the activity if there were multiple names/last names? something like dict = {'Name' : ['John','Jane'], 'Last Name': ['Smith','doe'], 'Activity':['Run', 'Jump', 'Hide', 'Swim', 'Eat', 'Sleep']}

Comment: Your example doesn't work

Comment: It doesnt work because John and Smith arent in there the same number of times as the activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `json_normalize`

```
out = pd.json_normalize(d,'Activity',['Name','Last Name'])
Out[160]: 
       0  Name Last Name
0    Run  John     Smith
1   Jump  John     Smith
2   Hide  John     Smith
3   Swim  John     Smith
4    Eat  John     Smith
5  Sleep  John     Smith
```

Input

```
d = {'Name' : ['John'], 'Last Name': ['Smith'], 'Activity':['Run', 'Jump', 'Hide', 'Swim', 'Eat', 'Sleep']}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you strictly have one pair of Name/Last Name, you can modify the dictionary so that pandas reads activity as a list

```
d = {k: [v] if len(v) > 1 else v for k, v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.explode('Activity')

    Name    Last Name   Activity
0   John    Smith       Run
0   John    Smith       Jump
0   John    Smith       Hide
0   John    Smith       Swim
0   John    Smith       Eat
0   John    Smith       Sleep
```